# Prevent Gnome from bounding windows

Tags: gnome

I'm using Gnome Classic and it tends to move windows to the edge of screen without my will.

- I can't leave a window partially off-screen (it moves into the screen once I've switched to another app)
- Sometimes Nautilus window placed in center of the screen moves down to the edge of the screen again and again.

Where is the magic checkbox to stop that?

**Update.** The problem is in Compiz plugin "Place Windows". Is there any replacements for that plugin? I want new windows to appear in screen center - that's all what I need from that plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug. Fixed at least in Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 0):

As you can read here:

[Disable auto maximizing windows](http://ubuntuguide.net/auto-maximizing-windows-ubuntu-12-04)

you have to do install CCSM:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

After installation, launch it and go to panel for configuration of the plugin *Grid*.

Select the tab *edges*, then look for the *resize actions* and set, as you prefer, the values of corners and edges of your screen.

*To settle things once and for all*, I suggest you to disable *Grid plugin*.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to ccsm (it was difficult to find how to run it when installed, so I'll leave it here: `ccsm` command). But Grid does not affect the problem I've mentioned. There's a Put plugin with "Avoid Offscreen" checkbox, but it was already disabled. So the problem remains.

Comment: I found. The plugin is called Place. But seems it does not have a setting for this weird behavior. If I'm disabling the entire plugin, new windows appear under the Gnome Panel. If I'm enabling it the originally mentioned problem appears. Any ideas?